# Unable to fetch record using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on Reactjs and i am trying to fetch data, Right now i am getting data from api in console( response) but unable to display data in page,Where i am wrong,In console i am getting data in following format

```
0:{id: '28', title: 'first blog', image: 'https://xxxx.jpg', description: 'ABC', status: 'active', …}
1:{id: '27', title: 'second blog', image: 'xxxxx.png', description: 'XYZ', status: 'active', …}
...
```

I tried with following code

```
export default function Article() {
  const { translate } = useLocales();
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getArticles().then((response) => {
        console.log(response); // getting data in console
        
      if (response.items) {
        const data = response.items.map((item) => {
          return {
            img: item.image,
            title: item.title,
            }
        });
        setArticles(data);
      }
    });
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Have you written any code to display the data?

Comment: @Unmitigated above code is in "component file" and i am using above component in "Homepage.js" (Article)

Comment: In order to display the data you have to write the code to display the data. But, based on the data (is each one an article?), it looks like you should shift the data fetching to a parent component and then `map` over the data to create new articles (with the Article component) with each object...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

response looks like an array, but you are accessing it through `response.items`.

Code should be like this:

```
export default function Article() {
    const { translate } = useLocales();
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getArticles().then((response) => {
            console.log(response); // getting data in console

            if (response) {
                const data = response.map((item) => {
                    return {
                        img: item.image,
                        title: item.title,
                    }
                });
                setArticles(data);
            }
        });
    }, []);
}
```